# T-SQL Dbmail ignore error/send email with/without attachment (dynamic email)

Tags: sql, t-sql, email-attachments, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I wrote a quick query which pulls out information from the system and puts it into an email when a task is completed. Each task has a numerical id, and that is the key link between data and my attachment.

The email runs the query for example on number: 15005. It pulls the data for 15005, and also looks for an attachment in the location named 15005.pdf

This works fine, however. I also need the query to work and send an email when there is no attachment. - Sometimes the paperwork doesn't arrive and we simply have no 15005.pdf.

So I need some form of way for the SQL to identify either that it's errored, and use an alternate email design without the attachment. Or to just ignore the error.

FYI the error in question is: Msg 22051 - "Attachment file is invalid"

I can post the query if it's needed, however this all works fine, it's just the email bit i'm stuck on:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = @Recipients,
@subject = @PONumber,
@body = @tableHTML,
@file_attachments = @Attach,
@profile_name = 'Email', 
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

Also, the @Attach in question is working successfully, as it's looking for the correct filename that WOULD exist.

Answer (score 0):

Not the neatest option, but as I was intending to run this on a scheduled job, I set step 1 to email with attachment, if it errored it moved to step 2. Which ran it without the attachment.